# If there exists a surjection $\phi\colon A\to B$ should there also exist a surjection $\phi\colon A\to C$ where $C\subseteq B$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If there exists a surjection $\phi\colon A\to B$ should there also exist a surjection $\phi\colon A\to C$ where $C\subseteq B$?

This is obvious for finite cases and also coutably infinite cases. I am mostly interested in the scenarios in which the sets involved are uncountable.

Comment: Sure.  Pick a point $c\in C$.  Then define $\psi(a)$ to be $\phi(a)$ if $\phi(a)\in C$ and set $\psi(a)=c$ otherwise.

Comment: @lulu- Ah should have thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: Technically you want to assume that $C$ isn't empty; otherwise there are no maps from $A$ to $C$ at all . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber Unless $A$ is empty too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, assuming that $C$ isn't empty. Let $c$ denote an arbitrary element from $C$ and $f$ a surjection from $A$ to $C$. Then
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & f(x) \in C \\ c & f(x) \notin C \end{cases}$$
is a surjection from $A$ to $C$.

Comment: How can you *assume* without loss of generality that $C$ is not empty? Is the empty set not a subset of $B$?

Comment: The definition of function $f:X\to Y$ says that $X$ and $Y$ must be non empty.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You're right, I've changed the wording. There is no function $A \to \emptyset$ if $A \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: @ajotatxe: That is blatantly false. $\varnothing$ is a function from $\varnothing$ to $\varnothing$.